# Aurelia: How to detect or register callback for when custom element is loaded and ready to interface with

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a pie chart custom element and I want to be able to configure what event sends the data to be rendered from the view model.

Right now the current solution is as follows (and feels a bit hacky)

**html**

```
<pie-chart ref="pc" event.bind="pc.event"></pie-chart>
```

**view model**

```
    attached() {
       this.pc.event = event_list.MY_EVENT;
   }
```

**pie chart custom element**

```
  attached() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      self.subscription = self.eventaggregator.subscribe(self.event, self.setPieData);
    },1000);
  }
```

This is just to get me started. But as you can see I'm having to wait until the page is done loading, or one second, to actually set the event subscription up. Otherwise event is null.

I've tried a few approaches such as using the propertyChanged() functionality of the bindable property `event` but that also does not work. All I want to do is know when I am able to interface with the custom element from the view model, then do so. Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the view model's assignment of `this.pc.event` have to be done in attached()? How about moving it to bind(), created() or the constructor?

**view model**

```
bind() {
    this.pc.event = event_list.MY_EVENT;
}
```

Comment: Setting the event in `bind()` from the view model and subscribing to the event in the `attached()` of the custom element is the correct answer. Thank you. You may want to edit your responses code block from `created()` to `bind()`. Thanks again!